# reactivecocoa confuse about sequence.array

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I want to get grouped array from [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4] to [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]].

I've written two types of code. The first one works fine, but the second one doesn't. anyone can tell me why? thanks

```
    RACSignal *signal = @[@1, @2, @3, @4,@2,@3,@3,@4,@4,@4].rac_sequence.signal;

// first
NSArray *arr0 = [[[signal
                groupBy:^(NSNumber *object) {
                    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object];
                }]
               map:^(RACSignal *signal) {
                   return signal.sequence;
               }].sequence
              map:^(RACSequence *sequence) {
                  return sequence.array;
              }].array;

// second
NSArray *arr1 = [[signal
               groupBy:^(NSNumber *object) {
                   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object];
               }]
              map:^(RACSignal *signal) {
                  return signal.sequence.array;
              }].sequence.array;
```